# Round rectangle in rectangle - how to detect coordinates in corners that are outside of round rectangle?

Tags: javascript, geometry, rounded-corners

I am struggling to find a way to solve this issue.

I am getting this picture 306px x 620px

[image]

It's an image with a rounded rectangle. In order to make the rounded rectangle only clickable I set border-radius: 80px; and this works.

Now I am trying to write a smart way in which I can test it and detect if (x, y) position of click (like on this image)

[image]

is actually outside of the rounded rectangle parameters

I had a similar idea like this https://www.jsparling.com/using-rectangles-to-fill-the-area-outside-of-a-circle/ but I want to check if there is some smart way to detect if (x, y) is outside of this rounded rectangle

Initially, I posted on https://math.stackexchange.com/ but they mention that is better to ask here.

Any help/idea would be appreciated.

---

**Edit 1**

Maybe more information:
Left, Top of the rectangle is 0,0

[image]

---

**Edit 2**

Reproducible environment https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvf3ue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

---

**Edit 3**

Just to clarify those are the things I know

```
    const height = 620;
    const width = 306;
```

And I know that `border-radius: 80px;` would prevent from clicking outside of this rounded rectangle (those small parts)

I am trying to write a test where I can check if the coordinate is not inside rounded rectangle area

---

**Update** - result

Thanks to both @Yves Daoust and @MBo

Since @MBo answered first with the correct answer I will mark his answer as correct.

If someone is interested in implementation - check it out

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4nwrd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With arc radius `R`, rectangle left top corner coordinate `Left, Top`, dimensions `Wdt` and `Hgt`, we can write the next condition for points outside:

```
Outside = (X < Left) or 
          (X > Left + Wdt) or 
          (Y < Top) or 
          (Y > Top + Hgt) or 
          Corner(X - Left - R - X, Y - Top - R, R) or
          Corner(X - Left - R, Top  + Hgt - R - Y, R) or
          Corner(Left + Wdt - R - X, Top  + Hgt - R - Y, R) or
          Corner(Left + Wdt - R - X, Y - Top - R, R)
```

where `Corner` is function to check if point lies in curved triangle:

```
function Corner(DX, DY, R) {
    return DX < 0 and DY < 0 and DX * DX + DY * DY > R * R
}
```

To find if point is inside - just inverse `Outside` result

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and input. I have one question - did you mean Left, Top -> of the rounded rectangle or rectangle -> since 0,0 (from rectangle) would eliminate all of the first four constraints

Comment: I mean Left, Top of full rectangle